# How define a fish shell function that searches for a pattern within certain files?

Tags: shell, fish

I want to create a function that has one required argument and two optional arguments:

```
(searchterm, filenamepattern='.*', grepopt='-in')
```

and searches the current directory recursively and prints a list of

```
files:linenumbers:linecontents
```

What is the best way to do this?

Both for dealing with function arguments in Fish, and for the find/grep command pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I came up with so far:

```
function findin --argument searchterm
    set -q argv[1]; and echo "Searching for $searchterm"; or begin;
        echo "searchterm is required."; return 1; end;
    set -q argv[2]; and set -l filenamepattern $argv[2]; or set filenamepattern ".*"
    set -q argv[3]; and set -l grepopt $argv[3]; or set grepopt '-in'

    find . -type f -print0 | grep -iz "$filenamepattern" | xargs -0 grep "$searchterm" $grepopt
    echo "just ran:\n find . -type f -print0 | grep -iz \"$filenamepattern\" | xargs -0 grep \"$searchterm\" $grepopt"
end
```

Invoked like this:

```
><>findin
searchterm is required.

><>findin 'love'
anyfile.html:343:/* research -> Healing of Love */

><>findin 'love' 'only.one'
only.one:343:/* research -> Healing of Love */

><>findin 'love' 'index.html' ''
index.html:/* case sensitive  without line#s-> healing of love */
```